# Count values in MySQL with specific ID

Tags: mysql, count

Ok, this should be simple:

```
ID | version | downloads
========================
 1 |   1.0   |     2
 1 |   1.1   |     4
 1 |   1.2   |     7
 1 |   1.3   |     3
 2 |   1.0   |     3
 2 |   2.0   |     3
 2 |   3.0   |    13
```

I like to get the downloads of a specific product (ID) no matter which version.
This doesn't work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS downloads FROM table WHERE ID = 1
```

should return 2 + 4 + 7 + 3 = **16**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your output says that you want to sum the downloads column.
so you have to use sum aggregate function..

```
   SELECT Sum(downloads) AS downloads FROM table WHERE ID = 1
```

If you want sum(downloads) for each ID,Just change the query as follow

```
 SELECT ID,Sum(downloads) AS downloads FROM table group by ID
```

If you need total record counts then only use Count

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count FROM table WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: +1 For being the only one to actually explain what `Count` do.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(downloads) AS downloads 
FROM   table 
WHERE  id = 1
```

[Sum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) adds the values
You can also use group by to return the sum for each id

```
SELECT SUM(downloads) AS downloads 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(downloads) FROM table WHERE ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a query that could show you all SUMs from all IDs then if you need you filter one in specific.

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(downloads) as TotalDownloads
  FROM table
 GROUP BY id;
```

If you need to filter a specific id just add `where id = 1`

The result for this would be:

```
ID | TotalDownloads
========================
 1 | 16
 2 | 19
```